# Django посоветуйте виджет для DateTimeRangeField

Tags: python, django

Модель:

```
from psycopg2.extras import DateTimeTZRange

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import DateTimeRangeField
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible

DateTimeTZRange = deconstructible(DateTimeTZRange, path='psycopg2.extras.DateTimeTZRange')


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Заголовок', max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField('Текст')
    likes = models.PositiveIntegerField('Лайки')
    dislikes = models.PositiveIntegerField('Дизлайки')
    active_range = DateTimeRangeField(default=DateTimeTZRange(None, None, '[]'))
```

Пробовал использовать AdminSplitDateTime виджет:

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        widgets = {
            'active_range': RangeWidget(widgets.AdminSplitDateTime)
        }
        fields = '__all__'


@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ArticleForm
```

вылетает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 606, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1634, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1522, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1554, in _changeform_view
    form_validated = form.is_valid()
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 185, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 180, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 381, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 399, in _clean_fields
    value = field.clean(value)
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 1035, in clean
    clean_data.append(field.clean(field_value))
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 148, in clean
    value = self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 462, in to_python
    result = super().to_python(value)
  File "/home/konstantin/github/test-task-for-rubyfire/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 379, in to_python
    value = value.strip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Посоветуйте виджет для DateTimeRangeField или как починить AdminSplitDateTime.

Comment: Скорее всего, для `DateTimeRangeField` надо писать свой виджет: это нестандартный `Field`

Answer (score 1):

Смог подружить DateTimeRangeField и AdminSplitDateTime

```
class CustomWidget(widgets.AdminSplitDateTime):
    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        temp = [widget.value_from_datadict(data, files, name + '_%s' % i) for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets)]
        return ' '.join(temp)


class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        widgets = {
            'active_range': RangeWidget(CustomWidget)
        }
        fields = '__all__'


@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ArticleForm
    list_display = ('title', 'likes', 'dislikes', 'final_sum')
```